# Update attribute at sign in with devise (after_set_user callback)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have the devise gem installed on my rails app. Also I have a boolean column:is_active in the stores table.

Each time a store tries to sign in I'm running the `Warden::Manager.after_set_user` callback along with the braintree code to find if the store has has an active or not subscription. And if the store has and active or not subscription I'm trying to update the is_active column to true or false.

But for some reason I can't get the is_active boolean to update!

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user :scope => :store do |store, auth, opts|

customer = Braintree::Customer.find('customer_id')
customer_card = customer.payment_methods[0].token
payment_method = Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(customer_card)
sub = payment_method.subscriptions[0]
sub.status

if Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active
  obj = Store.find_by_id(params[:id])
  obj.is_active = true
  obj.save!


else
  obj = Store.find_by_id(params[:id])
  obj.is_active = false
  obj.save!
end
end
```

And this is the code I'm using for devise in order to allow or block a store from signing in.

```
 def active_for_authentication?
    super && is_active?
 end

 def inactive_message
    "User not active, please subscribe!"
 end
```

Comment: Do you receive some kind of error or exception when saving?

Comment: @Theopap You can active field in `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)`

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano, no nothing!

Comment: @Vishal I placed my code in the application controller under the `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)` but the same thing happens... no error and it won't let me sign in

Comment: @Theopap are you sure that the `obj.save!` is being executed?

Comment: @Theopap 
Have you trie to use  update_column?

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

Instead of saving again.

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure @MatayoshiMariano, in the rails console when I try to sign in nothing appears!

Comment: @Theopap do you use a debugger like [pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails)? Try putting a `binding.pry` in the code to see if it is being executed

Comment: Write byebug before the save call and see if at least the application goes there.

Comment: Just getting this:  `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YZpVWN0BVrEc1juPjKYScnxdbIb/FRSV74TBVYL+PAbh/jo9xBlrwWmOBkmToDzHFNLZ/T3nqtJ36hW7SOwK7w==", "store"=>{"email"=>"example@hotmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Store Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."email" = ? ORDER BY "stores"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "example@hotmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]`